# Export DetachedCriteria default queries for model attributes

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm newbie with grails/gorm, I'm building and API for my frontend calls. I'm using DetachedCriteria for queries and filters and I'm seeing that I'm replicating too much code...

For each class of the model I have to write the DetachedCriteria to create the 'eq' and 'likes' (If I want to implements neq, gt,lt, etc I have to do the same) of each attribute.

My question is, are there any way to do it reusable for any model class?

**Model**

```
class Model{ 
    String id
    String code
    String name
    String url

...
```

**Service**

```
interface IModelService {
    Model get(Serializable id)

    void delete(Serializable id)

    Model save(Model model)
}


@Service(Model)
abstract class ModelService implements IModelService{
    private DetachedCriteria buildCriteria(Map params) {
        new DetachedCriteria(Model).build {
            if(params.q) {
                or{
                    ilike('name', "%${params.q}%")
                    ilike('code', "%${params.q}%")
                    ilike('url', "%${params.q}%")
                }
            }
            if(params.code) {
                eq('code', params.code)
            }
            if(params.name) {
                eq('name', params.name)
            }
            if(params.url) {
                eq('url', params.url)
            }
        }
    }

    List<Model> search(Map params) {
        buildCriteria(params).list(params) as List<Model>
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it creating with an external abstract class:

**Model**

```
@Service(Model)
abstract class ModelService extends DetachedCriteriaService implements IModelService {

    @Override
    Class getClazz(){
        Model
    }

    protected DetachedCriteria buildCriteria(Map params) {
        super.buildCriteria(params).build {}
    }

    ...
```

**External class**

```
import grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria

abstract class DetachedCriteriaService<T> {
    protected DetachedCriteria buildCriteria(Map params) {
        new DetachedCriteria(getClazz()).build {
            if(params.q) {
                or {
                    getQSearchFields().each {
                        ilike(it, "%${params.q}%")
                    }
                }
            }
            getFields().intersect(params.keySet()).each {
                List<String> parts = it.split(':')*.trim()
                String element = parts[0]
                String filter = parts[1] ?: "eq"
                switch (filter) { //TODO Implementar inList
                    case "eq":
                        eq element, params[element]
                        break
                    case "ne":
                        ne element, params[element]
                        break
                    case "gt":
                        gt element, params[element]
                        break
                    case "lt":
                        lt element, params[element]
                        break
                    case "ge":
                        ge element, params[element]
                        break
                    case "le":
                        le element, params[element]
                        break
                    case "like":
                        like element, params[element]
                        break
                    case "ilike":
                        ilike element, params[element]
                        break
                    default:
                        eq element, params[element]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    abstract Class getClazz()
```